# Records loaded from localStorage doesn't seem to become part of $scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

The url is http://kohlin.net/lab/angular/index.html 
Try to create a couple of contacts, try to edit one or more (yes,it gets deleted while editing) and delete one to see that it works.

The problem is when you reload. You are then not able to edit or delete individual contacts. It's like it doesn't even listen to the ng-click="editItem($index)" at all.

Even tried to implement ngStorage but that didn't help either. Any guesses?

**Update**
It appears I cannot include material.min.js (material design lite) If I remove it, everything works like a charm.

So the new question is. How can I make this app work WITH material design lite

(do I delete this question completely from stackoverflow and create a new one?)

Comment: Can you create a demo plunkr?

Comment: Sigh! I made a codepen and now that one  works... http://s.codepen.io/jkohlin/debug/rOVzPO?

Comment: And here is a codepen of my original code, that still doesn't work: http://codepen.io/jkohlin/pen/XmbeNp?editors=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a weird CSS issue when material icons containers overlay buttons preventing click events from reaching handlers.

Try putting ngClick on the buttons instead of `i`:

```
<div class="mdl-card__menu">
    <button ng-click="editItem($index)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button> 
    <button ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"><i class="material-icons ">delete</i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Does that have to do with bubbling? Removing the js-file of material design lite also worked. So there's something with with mdl js not playing well with eventhandling I supose.